# what is wrong with this Pandas and txt file code

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm using pandas to open a CSV file that contains data from spotify, meanwhile, I have a txt file that contains various artists names from that CSV file. What I'm trying to do is get the value from each row of the txt and automatically search them in the function I've done.

```
import pandas as pd
import time

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
df = df[['artists', 'name', 'year']]

def buscarA():
  start = time.time()
  newdf = (df.loc[df['artists'].str.contains(art)])
  stop = time.time()
  tempo = (stop - start)
  print (newdf)
  e = ('{:.2f}'.format(tempo))
  print (e)

with open("teste3.txt", "r") as f:
for row in f:
    art = row
    buscarA()
```

but the output is always the same:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [artists, name, year]
Index: []
```

Comment: Try using `newdf = df.loc[df['artists'].str.contains(art).index]`. Also, I would recommend to use `def buscarA(art)`, then using `buscarA(art)` in your text file.

Comment: After adding .index it returns the complete data frame instead of the one with only the filtred data. Thanks on the buscarA(art) tip.

Comment: Yes, you're right. There's no problem in this chunk at all. I've posted an answer. Please see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that when you read the lines of your file in Python, it also gets the line break per row so that you have to strip it off.

Let's suppose that the first line of your `teste3.txt` file is "James Brown". It'd be read as "James Brown\n" and not recognized in the search.

Changing the last chunk of your code to:

```
with open("teste3.txt", "r") as f:
    for row in f:
        art = row.strip()
        buscarA()
```

should work.